# php delete subarray from array by value

Tags: php, arrays

i have a array:

```
Array




( 
    [1] => Array 
    ( 
    [id] => 352 
    [name] => account_3 
   [ips] => 



[tech_prefix] =>
   [password] => 
    [id_voip_hosts] =>
    [proxy_mode] => 
    [auth_type] => ani 
   [ani] => 1345436
[accname] => 
[protocol] => 
[port] => 
[orig_enabled] => 1 
[term_enabled] => 
[orig_capacity] => 
[term_capacity] => 
[orig_rate_table] => 
[term_rate_table] => 
[id_dr_plans] => 
[orig_groups] => 
[term_groups] => 
[notes] => 
) 
[2] => Array 
( 
[id] => 354 
[name] => account_4 
[ips] => 
[tech_prefix] => 
[password] => 
[id_voip_hosts] => 
[proxy_mode] => 
[auth_type] => ani 
[ani] => 472367427 
[accname] => 
[protocol] => 
[port] => 
[orig_enabled] => 1 
[term_enabled] => 
[orig_capacity] => 
[term_capacity] => 
[orig_rate_table] => 
[term_rate_table] => 
[id_dr_plans] => 
[orig_groups] => 
[term_groups] => 
[notes] => 
) 
[3] => Array 
( 
[auth_type] => ani 
[name] => 472367427 
[ani] => 472367427 
[orig_enabled] => Array 
( 
[0] => on 
) 
) 
)`
```

The main array coult contain many "sub arrays" from [1] to [10] for example.
What i need: i need to delete "subarray" witch have [any]=> $todel
For example, $todel = 472367427, this means that array must contain subarrays [1] and [3] and so on.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts about how to solve it?

Comment: How does value 472367427 means that you must contain subarrays [1] and [3]?  Also, I'm still unsure about what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: Oh, and, please, indent your code.

Comment: simply you want if not set ani index then delete that row the you can use if(!isset($array[$i]['any']{ unset($array[$i])}

Answer (score 0):

That's easy with `unset`:

```
$yourIndex = 2;
unset( $yourArray[$yourIndex] ); // this will remove the third element, index: 2
```

With `unset` array indexes will remain the same, so if you want to re-shift the indexes, use `array_splice` function like this:

```
$yourIndex = 2;
array_splice($yourArray, $yourIndex, 1); // "1" in the last argument indicates how many elements will be removed starting from the $yourIndex value
```

More on:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

Comment: and how to get that index by ani?

Comment: @user2563906 - What is "ani"? This is an example how to remove any of the elements contained in the array. You can use this snippet to get the idea how to remove individual elements from the array.

Comment: $yourIndex = 2;
unset( $yourArray[$yourIndex] ); is working, but second problem. As i understanded, i must find key of array. the array_search will search in all "subarray's"? if i run array_search ($todel, $mainarray); will it search in array[0] array[1] and so on?

Comment: @user2563906 - What is the problem?